# Copy a local file onto Windows Azure VM using Terraform

Tags: azure, terraform, winrm

I'm trying to use provisioner "file" to copy a local file onto a Windows Azure VM after creating it using Terraform.

I have enabled the custom script extension using:

```
resource "azurerm_virtual_machine_extension" "VM" {
  name                 = "WinRM"
  location             = "${azurerm_resource_group.VM.location}"
  resource_group_name  = "${azurerm_resource_group.VM.name}"
  virtual_machine_name = "${azurerm_virtual_machine.VM01.name}"
  publisher            = "Microsoft.Compute"
  type                 = "CustomScriptExtension"
  type_handler_version = "1.8"
```

I have port 5985 open in my NSG:

```
security_rule {
  name            = "AllowWinRM"
  priority          = 300
  direction         = "Inbound"
  access            = "Allow"
  protocol          = "Tcp"
  source_port_range           = "*"
  destination_port_range      = "5985"
  source_address_prefix       = "*"
  destination_address_prefix  = "*"
  }
```

My OS config is set to:

```
os_profile_windows_config {
    provision_vm_agent = true
    winrm {
       protocol="http"
     }
  }
```

Finally I try to copy the file:

```
resource "null_resource" "VM" {
  provisioner "file" {
    source      = "output.txt"
    destination = "c:\\temp\\output.txt"

    connection {
      type     = "winrm"
      user     = "${var.adminusername}"
      password = "${var.adminpassword}"
      host     = "${azurerm_public_ip.VM1_pip.ip_address}"
      port     = "5985"
      timeout  = "20m"
    }
  }
}
```

Every time I try to 'apply' this it hits the 20 minute timeout and fails with the following error (public ip removed):

> azurerm_virtual_machine_extension.VM:
>   compute.VirtualMachineExtensionsClient#CreateOrUpdate: Failure sending
>   request: StatusCode=200 -- Original Error: Code="" Message=""
>   * null_resource.buildagent: timeout - last error: unknown error Post http://PublicIP:5985/wsman: dial tcp PublicIP:5985: connectex: A
>   connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly
>   respond after a period of time, or established connection failed
>   because connected host has failed to respond.

First of all, am I doing this correctly? Everything seems to be set up correctly but that last step keeps failing.

Answer (score 0):

WinRM is not enabled by default on the standard images. `CustomScriptExtension` works well if you upload in advance the script to a publicly accessible URL, like an Azure Storage Blob.

I do this using my TFS CI pipeline (see picture) which triggers at each commit: the files are collected and uploaded to Azure Blob.

[image: CI steps]

The Terraform `azurerm_virtual_machine_extension` has similar code

```
  settings = <<SETTINGS
    {
      "fileUris": [
        "${var.vm_customscript_baseurl}/UpgradePowershell.vbs",
        "${var.vm_customscript_baseurl}/Win8.1AndW2K12R2-KB3191564-x64.msu"
        ],
      "commandToExecute": "cmd /c cscript UpgradePowershell.vbs"
    }
SETTINGS
```

or, in case of the DSC extension

```
  settings = <<SETTINGS
    {
      "configuration": {
        "url": "${var.vm_dsc_package_url}",
        "script": "VotingWebConfiguration.ps1",
        "function": "VotingWebRoleConfiguration"
      }
    }
SETTINGS
```

Comment: i think he accounts for that in his config

Comment: Yes - I was under the impression that WinRM is enabled by the os config. I can see that it is enabled in the VM extensions. Also i'd prefer to avoid having to upload a script to storage i advance as this script has potential to change so would like to take it from source control.

Comment: I solve this through my CI pipeline: it collect the scripts and publish them to Blob Storage. The CI is triggered by any commit and it per-branch containers/folders.

Comment: @GiulioVian Ah ok, i'll give that a go as a workaround for now. How do you then copy this to your VM? Can you share your step/config?

Comment: Thank you. I've got a script that will upload the files to storage but I was after the Terraform that you run to get the scripts from storage and execute them. Do you have this to share?

Comment: Thank you again - can this only be used with publicly accessible files? My files are in a private storage account and it seems that Terraform can't access it.

Comment: Must be a public accessible URL, that is the _Access Policy_ must allow *Blob* access (anonymous read access for blobs only)

Comment: Damn, not something I can do unfortunately. These scripts need to be kept private.

Comment: You can keep the container private and generate short-term SAS tokens for the container during deployment. You can do this by running a powershell script with New-AzStorageContainerSASToken. If you run this command without specifying start and end times, the token will expire an hour post creation. Anyone with the token will be able to access the container during the validity period, however, as long as the tokens are generated in a secure environment this is a secure solution.